# String modification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have fetched data from database with column type TEXT. Lets say the data that is fetch is a paragraph with some unique keywords.

For instance.

```
I am -b- Batman -.b-
```

Now what this `-b- and -.b-` is intended to do is whatever lies with in these must be Bold

Like

```
I am **Batman**
```

How do I achieve this? I am using PHP and MySQL and also if this is achievable in jquery javascript please tell

and in database it is stored just like this

```
I am -b- Batman -.b-
```

Comment: Can you amend the format you store in the database? Markdown would seem *far* more appropriate than this half-assed encoding.

Comment: use `str_ireplace()` for this

Comment: you can use the [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

Comment: mb somebody show us regular expression?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in database it is stored just like the first line! Check I have updated my question

Comment: @ImmortalDude I am picking the string that is inside -b- and -.b- and then making its font BOLD. it is just like <strong> Batman </strong>

Comment: @Dragos I am picking the string that is inside -b- and -.b- and then making its font BOLD. it is just like <strong> Batman </strong>

Comment: @Matt yes and you can do that with `str_ireplace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace these by `str_replace`

```
$str = $result['paragraph'];
echo str_replace('-.b-', '</strong>', str_replace('-b-', '<strong>', $str));
```

and in javascript:

```
var str = '<?php echo $result['paragraph']; ?>';
str.replace('-b-', '<strong>').replace('-.b-', '</strong>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace it with HTML-Tags. Like BBCode.

```
$i = 0;
$open=array("-b-","-i-");
$close=array("-.b-","-.i-");
$openhtml=array("<b>","<i>");
$closehtml=array("</b>","</i>");

while(count($open) > i){

    if (strpos($text, $open[i]) !== false) {
        echo str_replace("$open[i]","openhtml[i]","$text");
        echo str_replace("$close[i]","closehtml[i]","$text");
    }
    i++;
}
```

I hope i could help you.

*dont forget to accept an answer;)*

Answer (score 1):

Just use str_replace. If you want HTML:

```
$string = str_replace('-b-', '<strong>', $string);
$string = str_replace('-.b-', '</strong>', $string);
```

Or if you really meant the `*` characters

```
$string = str_replace('-b-', '**', $string);
$string = str_replace('-.b-', '**', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `preg_matches`, build functions and do all sorts of things to achieve what you want. But since you simply want to replace `-b-` and `-.b-` with `**` I want to suggest using `str_replace`.

```
$result['paragraph'] = str_replace(array('-b-', '-.b-'), "**", $result['paragraph']);
```

#### In addition

You can still use `preg_replace` if you feel like it.

```
$string = "There is a white -b- dog -.b- in my neighbor's garden";

$string = preg_replace("/-b-(.+?)-.b-/is", "**$1**", $string);

echo $string;
```

#### Source:

- [str_replace() - Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `whitespace` or `attributes` then this will do:

```js
str = 'I am -b- -i- Batman -.i- -.b- -br.-';

console.log(
  str.replace(/-\.?\w+\.?-/ig, function(n) {
  m = n
    .replace('-.', '-/')
    .replace('.-', '/-')
    .replace('-', '<');

  m = m
    .split("").reverse().join("")
    .replace('-', '>');

  m = m
    .split("").reverse().join("")

  return m;
})
)
```

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, use `str_replace();`
In Javascript, `replace();`